# Iterating through Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying below array to populate in   but getting error:**Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in D:\Apache24\htdocs\services\xxxx.php on line 40**
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [actor_id] => 2
            [first_name] => NICK
            [last_name] => WAHLBERG
            [last_update] => 2006-02-15 04:34:33
        )

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [actor_id] => 3
        [first_name] => ED
        [last_name] => CHASE
        [last_update] => 2006-02-15 04:34:33
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [actor_id] => 4
        [first_name] => JENNIFER
        [last_name] => DAVIS
        [last_update] => 2006-02-15 04:34:33
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [actor_id] => 5
        [first_name] => JOHNNY
        [last_name] => LOLLOBRIGIDA
        [last_update] => 2006-02-15 04:34:33
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [actor_id] => 6
        [first_name] => BETTE
        [last_name] => NICHOLSON
        [last_update] => 2006-02-15 04:34:33
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [actor_id] => 7
        [first_name] => GRACE
        [last_name] => MOSTEL
        [last_update] => 2006-02-15 04:34:33
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [actor_id] => 8
        [first_name] => MATTHEW
        [last_name] => JOHANSSON
        [last_update] => 2006-02-15 04:34:33
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [actor_id] => 9
        [first_name] => JOE
        [last_name] => SWANK
        [last_update] => 2006-02-15 04:34:33
    )

[8] => stdClass Object
    (
        [actor_id] => 10
        [first_name] => CHRISTIAN
        [last_name] => GABLE
        [last_update] => 2006-02-15 04:34:33
    )

[9] => stdClass Object
    (
        [actor_id] => 11
        [first_name] => ZERO
        [last_name] => CAGE
        [last_update] => 2006-02-15 04:34:33
    )
)
```

I am using the function below:
public function encodeHtml($responseData) {

```
    $htmlResponse = "<table border='1'>";
    foreach($responseData as $key=>$value) {
            $htmlResponse .= "<tr><td>". $key. "</td><td>". $value. "</td></tr>";
    }
    $htmlResponse .= "</table>";
    return $htmlResponse;       
}
```

What is wrong I am doing here. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to print whole object as string here:
`$htmlResponse .= "<tr><td>". $key. "</td><td>". $value. "</td></tr>";`

You should print every object variable separately, e.g. to print first_name of actor:
`$htmlResponse .= "<tr><td>". $key. "</td><td>". $value->first_name. "</td></tr>";`

Comment: How I can make it dynamic. Mean to say it's a method for iterating data for any value. I don't want to make it hard coded... something like  value of a key

Comment: @Kartikeya you can use additional `foreach` to itterate throu all public object variables. E.g.: `foreach($responseData as $key=>$value) {foreach($value as $vkey=>$vvalue) {
            $htmlResponse .= "<tr><td>". $vkey. "</td><td>". $vvalue. "</td></tr>";}
    }`

Comment: I am trying like this:$htmlResponse .= "<tr><td>". $key. "</td><td>". $value->$responseData[$key]. "</td></tr>";

Comment: Can you help me with complete lines of code for output as

Comment: Id1 Fname1 Lname1 Last_update1<br />Id2 Fname2 Lname2 Last_update2... and so on

Comment: @Kartikeya `foreach($responseData as $key=>$value) {foreach($value as $vkey=>$vvalue) { $htmlResponse .=$vvalue." ";} . $htmlResponse .= "<br/>";}`

Comment: public function encodeHtml($responseData) { 
  
  $htmlResponse = "<table border='1'>";
  foreach($responseData as $key=>$value) 
  {
   $htmlResponse .="<tr>";
   foreach($value as $vkey=>$vvalue) 
    { 
     $htmlResponse .= "<td>". $vkey. "</td><td>". $vvalue. "</td>";
 } 
 $htmlResponse .="<tr>";
}
  $htmlResponse .= "</table>";
  return $htmlResponse;  
 }

Answer (score 0):

When using foreach from responseData you get each elemt. So the value gonna be a class and when

```
$htmlResponse .= "<tr><td>". $key. "</td><td>". $value. "</td></tr>";
```

The $value is a class wich is as the error said can not be converted to a string.